# React navigation navigate back to screen from createBottomTabNavigation without Tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have 2 stacks, one for user, and one for guests, which have some screens in common. If the user is logged in/authenticated, i want to direct them to the TabsPage where the user can find buttons to the profile and similar logged in user specific functionality.

If the user decides to browse the app without logging in, i redirect him to one of the screens that are in the TabsScreen, without showing the tabs at the bottom as it holds logged in user specific functionality. I am doing this by using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen A')
```

My navigation stacks are similar to the below:

```
const user = createStackNavigator({
    Tabs: TabsScreen // contains Screen A (common screen) , Screen B (logged in access only), Screen C (logged in access only)
    Screen1 : Screen1,  //from here on these are screens that we navigate to from Screen A
    Screen2 :Screen2
    .....
})

const guest = createStackNavigator({
  Screen1 : Screen1 (common with user stack),
Screen2 : Screen 2 (common with user stack),

})
```

When I am in guest mode, and navigate from Screen A to Screen 1, and try to go back, using `this.props.navigation.goBack()` I am landing on the Tabs page, where as what I want to achieve is going back to Screen A without the tab bar as the guest should not have access to it .

How can I achieve this? I am using version 4 of react-native-navigation
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems I wasn't including my common screens correctly in both stacks, once all of the were included it seemed to work fine!